# Sql Join Query to Get record on date bases with sum of OrderDelivery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name AS ItemName, 
    CONVERT(varchar, dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.CreatedOn, 1) AS [mm/dd/yy], 
    SUM(dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.DeliveredQuantity) AS DeliveredQuantity
FROM
    dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Customers ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Customers.BusinessUnitId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Items ON dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.BusinessUnitId = dbo.Items.BusinessUnitId 
              AND dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.ItemId = dbo.Items.ItemId
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Customers.Name, dbo.Items.Name, dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail.CreatedOn
```

I write this query to get all record with sum of `DeliveredQuantity` on base of date. But SQL return me all the data that I need but he is not returning me the sum of `DeliveredQuantity`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: **WHAT** concrete RDBMS are you using? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? DB2? MySQL?  Please add a relevant tag.

Comment: Also: please add some **sample data**, the output you're currently getting, and explain *why* the value you're getting is not correct

Comment: What does it return in the sum of the orderdelivery? Your GROUP BY might be too detailed...

Comment: i am using SQL Server

Comment: GenXApp23 Product 1  07/06/15 300
GenXApp23 Product 1  07/06/15 200
GenXApp23 Product 2  07/06/15 150
GenXApp23 Product 2          07/06/15 100

Comment: GenXApp23 Product 1 07/06/15 300
GenXApp23 Product 1 07/06/15 200
GenXApp23 Product 2 07/06/15 150
GenXApp23 Product 2 07/06/15 100  i need some of last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the date:

```
SELECT c.Name, i.Name AS ItemName, 
       CONVERT(varchar(10), od.CreatedOn, 1) AS [mm/dd/yy], 
       SUM(od.DeliveredQuantity) AS DeliveredQuantity
FROM dbo.OrderDeliveryDetail od INNER JOIN
     dbo.Customers c
     ON od.BusinessUnitId = c.BusinessUnitId  INNER JOIN
     dbo.Items i
     ON od.BusinessUnitId = i.BusinessUnitId AND
       od.ItemId = i.ItemId
GROUP BY c.Name, i.Name, CONVERT(varchar(10), od.CreatedOn, 1);
-------------------------^
```

Presumably, `CreatedOn` also has a time component, which would result in multiple rows for each date.

Also notice how the query is easier to understand *and* to write because of the use of table aliases.  And, *never* use `varchar()` without a length in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context, and you should be explicit to prevent future errors.